# Paraview: View a 2D Projection of a 3D object

Tags: 3d, 2d, visualization, paraview

Are there any options to get a 2D projection of the following 3D bone as shown below in **Paraview**?

[image]

The 2D projection contour line could look like the following (picture shown as an example, please ignore the projection plane):

[image]

Comment: You realize that this image itself is a 2D projection? Unless you mean projecting the points orthographically onto an arbitrary plane?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have updated the question with an example of what I look for (coming from a 2D image). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want to project to a plane at z=0. You can use the **Calculator** filter to project each point (x, y, z) to (x, y, 0). Turn on `Coordinate Results` and set the expression to `coordsX*iHat + coordsY*jHat`. Next, use the **Feature Edges** filter to produce a contour line of the projected geometry. This may give you something qualitatively similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And suppose I wanted to project to an arbitrary plane, how would the equation be different in that case?